Selecionar elementos en CSS no hermanos
Quiero hacer una tabs con solo CSS pero no logro conseguirlo, necesito que las tabs esten en un div diferente al div del contenido.
Les agrego el código HTML y el CSS que tengo, tambien uso TailwindCSS:


.tabs #tab1:checked~.contenido .contenido1,
.tabs #tab2:checked~.contenido .contenido2 {
  display: block;
}

.tab-content {
  display: none;
}
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>

<div class="container mx-auto">
  <!-- Tabs -->
  <div class=" flex flex-col">
    <div class="tabs">
      <input type="radio" name="tabs" id="tab1" class="hidden" checked />
      <label for="tab1" class="cursor-pointer bg-blue-500 p-3 text-center text-white md:w-1/6">About the private charter</label>
      <input type="radio" name="tabs" id="tab2" class="hidden" />
      <label for="tab2" class="cursor-pointer bg-blue-500 p-3 text-center text-white md:w-1/6">Activities during the charter</label>
    </div>
    <div class="contenido flex-row  p-10">
      <div id="content1" class="contenido1 tab-content mt-5 rounded-md  p-5 shadow-md">
        <p>Get to experience reefs with abundant.</p>
      </div>
      <div id="content2" class="contenido2 tab-content mt-5 rounded-md  p-5 shadow-md">
        <p>Content for Activities during the charter.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>




Hola Jesus, se puede lograr, pero sería necesario mover los input radio, ¿te interesa?

El código que tienes ahora mismo no va a funcionar porque .contenido no es un hermano de #tab1 o #tab2, lo es su contenedor .tabs. Por eso, esos selectores no seleccionan nada realmente.
Sin cambiar la estructura del código HTML, se podría conseguir lo que quieres usando la pseudo-clase :has() y el combinador de elemento adyacente (+) o de elemento subsiguiente (~):

Comprueba que .tabs contiene un #tabs1 o #tabs2 que estén marcados usando :has. De ese modo, aunque estás comprobando los valores de #tabs1 o #tabs2 el "foco" del selector sigue en .tabs.

.contenido es el hermano de .tabs, así que necesitarás un + o un ~ para seleccionarlo al estar después en el código. A partir de ahí, el resto de tu selector queda igual.


Aquí lo puedes ver funcionando con el código de tu pregunta:


.tabs:has(#tab1:checked) + .contenido .contenido1,
.tabs:has(#tab2:checked) + .contenido .contenido2 {
  display: block;
}

.tab-content {
  display: none;
}
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>

<div class="container mx-auto">
  <!-- Tabs -->
  <div class=" flex flex-col">
    <div class="tabs">
      <input type="radio" name="tabs" id="tab1" class="hidden" checked />
      <label for="tab1" class="cursor-pointer bg-blue-500 p-3 text-center text-white md:w-1/6">About the private charter</label>
      <input type="radio" name="tabs" id="tab2" class="hidden" />
      <label for="tab2" class="cursor-pointer bg-blue-500 p-3 text-center text-white md:w-1/6">Activities during the charter</label>
    </div>
    <div class="contenido flex-row  p-10">
      <div id="content1" class="contenido1 tab-content mt-5 rounded-md  p-5 shadow-md">
        <p>Get to experience reefs with abundant.</p>
      </div>
      <div id="content2" class="contenido2 tab-content mt-5 rounded-md  p-5 shadow-md">
        <p>Content for Activities during the charter.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>



